# Linux Suse 11 and apache - httpd.conf

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, httpd.conf, sles11

I have one problem and I hope you could help me.

I disable http and now using only HTTPS- SSL. In **httpd.conf** I use:

```
ProxyPass /comp1/ htt_://192.168.1.5/
ProxyPass /comp2/ htt_://192.168.1.6/
```

Everything works fine, but..

How can I disable default page (`index.php`)?

`http://192.168.1.0/comp1` I go to `http://192.168.1.5/` (that's OK)

When I write `http://192.168.1.0` in address bar it become `index.php` page that I don't need !! How to disable that ?

---

**One more question**

When I make in `ProxyPass` some URL, e.g. `https://192.168.5.5/apex/f?p=220:1`, I have problem with `?`

In URL I see that `apex/f%3Fp=220:1` is not allowed.

How to repair that? I've added `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` in httpd.conf. but it doesn't work or I don't know how to use it.

Comment: You should stick with 1 question per question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your DirectoryIndex line from your configuration, or set it to something that isn't index.php.  You'll then either get a directory index (i.e: a listing of the files in that directory), or a Directory Index Forbidden error if you don't have directory indexes enabled (ie: Options -Indexes)